# how to print alternate fibonacci number by using java programing?

Tags: java

```
class fib
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int n=0,p=1,k,count=10;
System.out.println(n+" "+p);
for(int i=2;i<count;++i)
{
k=n+p;
System.out.println(" "+k);
n=p;
p=k;
}
}
}
```

that code print a Fibonacci series 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 like that but i want alternate fib number like 0,1,3,8,21

Comment: Since you have to calculate all the Fibonacci numbers (assuming you are not using the O(1) formula), how about storing all the values and then print the index you want? (like a for-loop with an increment of 2)

Answer (score 0):

at the point you are printing your output try

```
if(i%2==0)
     System.out.println(" "+k);
```

depending on what you want to print the condition maybe

```
if(i%2==1)
```

Working Example below

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int n=0,p=1,k,count=10;
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i)
    {
        k=n+p;
        if(i%2==0)
            System.out.println(" "+k);
        n=p;
        p=k;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing alternate values only by using the index `i` as below:

```
class fib
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n=0,p=1,k,count=10;
        System.out.println(n);
        for(int i=2;i<count;++i)
        {
            if(i%2==0) continue; // add this line
            k=n+p;
            System.out.println(" "+k);
            n=p;
            p=k;
        }
    }
}
```